# Checkbox aligned with other buttons

Tags: html, css

I my html page I have a checkbox and two buttons aligned horizontally.  These are populated dynamically through a PHP function.  I find aligning the checkbox to exactly the same size as buttons and in line with buttons difficult.

The following is a minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript file upload</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">   
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 text-center">
<img src="" width="200" height="200" class="img"/>
<h6>Test Image</h6>

<input type="checkbox" id="'.$imgnam.'" title="Select Image" name="matchedImage" value="'.$imgnam.'" >

<button class="actButton" id="tbutton" onclick="downloadImage(this.id)" title="Download Image" style="background-color: #CECECE;border: none;color: white;
padding:6px 10px;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;margin:10px 0px 22px 0px"><i class="fa fa-download"  style="color:#040727"></i></button>

<button class="actButton dropbtn" id="shareImage" onclick="shareImage(this.id)" title="Share Image" style="background-color:#CECECE;border: none;color: white;
padding:6px 10px;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;margin:10px 0px 22px 0px"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"  style="color:#040727"></i></button>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I apply css to checkbox such as :

```
input[type=checkbox] {
        width: 10em;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        height: 10em;
        border: 0.2em solid black;
        padding-top: 3px;
    }
```

The box appears few pixels above the button.  How do I align the checkbox with the buttons.  Attaching an image output[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `padding` and add the following to `.actButton`:

> ```
> display: inline-block;  
> vertical-align: middle;
> line-height: 32px;
> height: 32px;
> width: 30px
> ```

Increase the `font-size` to 18px. Add `.actButton` class to checkbox as well and remove everything but the `border` and `appearance` properties.

Also the containing `<div>` has been changed to a `<fieldset>` and class `.col-sm-2` was changed to `.col-sm-6` at `-2` means that there's less space as the screen gets bigger, did you really want backwards behavior? If so just change back to `.col-sm-2`. The `<main class='container'>` and `<section class='row'>` was added as well (normally these tags would be `<div>` but it's just easier to read using semantically correct tags).

---

### Demo

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.actButton {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #CECECE;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 0px 22px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript file upload</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<main class='container'>
  <section class='row'>
  <fieldset class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="200" height="200" class="img" />
    <h6>Test Image</h6>

    <input type="checkbox" title="Select Image" name="matchedImage" class='actButton'>

    <button class="actButton dropbtn" id="tbutton" title="Download Image"><i class="fa fa-download" style="color:#040727"></i></button>

    <button class="actButton" id="shareImage" title="Share Image"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" style="color:#040727"></i></button>

  </fieldset>
  </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean `em`? It's `mm` in your code.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 10em;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    height: 10em;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: sorry its em...I tried your option but still getting a similar result....will update with a picture

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your css for the checkbox

```
vertical-align: middle;
```